# Number of Values Count

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
pd.value_counts(KT3['user_answer'])
```

I have a dataset of large number of students , attempting Mcqs options of the questions , (Options are  A,B,C,D and NONE) when i do **pd.value_counts** it gives the number of times A,B,C,D are selected but it is not showing how many times NONE option is selected.. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the argument dropna=False

```py
pd.value_counts(KT3['user_answer'], dropna=False)
```

or

```py
KT3['user_answer'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Comment: You can marked as acepted answer to show that it's solved.